# swipe guesture for tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have added `tableview` as `subview` and I have added `swipe gesture` to `tableview`. Swipe is not working. `Pan gesture` is working fine (just tested). `Swipe gesture` it not working. I wanna move the table to the right. So I wanna trigger animation only when swipe right is recognized. but swipe itself is not recognized.

```
panelGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closePanel:)];
   [panelGesture setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

    [panel addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use more then one gesture recognizer then you need to implement following delegate method of the gesture recognizer to make them work both

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

respectively you need to return `YES`

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code...

In .h file or private scope in .m file

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftToRightSwipGesture;
```

In .m file where you want to add the gesture recognizer there place this code...

```
leftToRightSwipGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sampleGesture)];
    [leftToRightSwipGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [dashboardInventoryTableView addGestureRecognizer:leftToRightSwipGesture];
```

In .m file sample method for the gesture

```
-(void)sampleGesture
{
    NSLog(@"Gesture Recognized");
}
```

Comment: This is what am really doing too. But swipe doesn't trigger at all. I have accepted Mert's answer, thats what I was really looking for.

Answer (score 1):

May be it Helps You but I'm not sure ,Try like this It Will work in my case it's working fine

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swiper = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closePanel)] autorelease];
    swiper.delegate=self;
    [swiper setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [tableview addGestureRecognizer:swiper];
```

And give delegate `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` in .h file

Comment: Sorry I've forgot the mention that. I have given delegate too. Still it's not working